# Ajax/PHP/JavaScript form submit with local storage value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit data and also a local storage value into my mysql database from the one ajax post. I can do one or the other but not both at the same time.

```
  var dataString =  'title=' + title + '&level=' + level + '&dateTo=' + dateTo + '&dateFrom=' + dateFrom + '&description=' + description ;
if (title == '' || level == '' || dateFrom == '' || dateTo == '' || description == '')
{
    alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
//AJAX code to submit form.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8888/EduSubOct/jobpost.php",
        data: dataString,  
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            alert("Information Entered Successfully");

        }
    });

   }
  return false;
}
```

in the above code, I am using data: dataString and below you will see I am using the local storage value object. I want to post both of these data strings/objects into one row in my database on one click button. You can see my code below that shows the local storage submission from Ajax.

```
function myFunctionjob() {


  // Returns successful data submission message when the entered 
 information is stored in database.


  //AJAX code to submit form.
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8888/EduSubOct/jobpost.php",
        data: { storageValue: localStorage.getItem("email"); } 
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            alert("Information Entered Successfully");

        }
      });

  }
```

My php works fine when done as two separate ajax posts. Ideally I would like in one Ajax post to the database. Any help on how I can sumbit both the dataString and the local storage value at the one time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just Include both `datastring` and value from local storage in the data section of ajax request.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8888/EduSubOct/jobpost.php",
    data: { storageValue: localStorage.getItem("email"), dataString: dataString} 
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        alert("Information Entered Successfully");
    }
  });
```

here on the server, you can access localstorage value as `$_POST['storageValue']` and data string object as `$_POST['dataString']`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Quick question, I have my access to dataString as '$title2 = $_POST['title'];
$level2 = $_POST['level'];
$dateFrom2 = $_POST['dateFrom'];
$dateTo2 = $_POST['dateTo'];
$description2 = $_POST['description'];' , would this be different as I access it like you said '$_POST['dataString']

Comment: inline `include_once 'dbh.php';

 //Here we fetch the data from the URL that was passed from our HTML form
$userDetails = $_POST['storageValue'];
$title2 = $_POST['title'];
$level2 = $_POST['level'];
$dateFrom2 = $_POST['dateFrom'];
$dateTo2 = $_POST['dateTo'];
$description2 = $_POST['description'];
   
       $sql = "INSERT INTO jobs (title, level,  dateTo, dateFrom, description, email) VALUES ('$title2', '$level2', '$dateFrom2', '$dateTo2','$description2','$userDetails');";
     
       mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
`

Comment: just print_r($_POST['dataString']); and then you can see the data coming through `dataString`. You can access the subsequent data as $_POST['dataString']['title'], $_POST['dataString']['level']

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek! Ill have a go at that

Comment: $userEmail = $_POST['userEmail'];

$title2 = $_POST['dataString']['title'];
$level2 = $_POST['dataString']['level'];
$dateFrom2 = $_POST['dataString']['dateFrom'];
$dateTo2 = $_POST['dataString']['dateTo'];
$description2 = $_POST['dataString']['description'];
   
       $sql = "INSERT INTO jobs (title, level,  dateTo, dateFrom, description, email) VALUES ('$title2', '$level2', '$dateFrom2', '$dateTo2','$description2','$userEmail');";
     
       mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
 Any suggestions?